Linear mixed model for crossed repeated measures desing
I am trying to analyse a longitudinal experimental psychology dataset. Each participant completed a task in which their reaction times to two different stimuli (here I'll call them Low and High) were collected. The task had multiple blocks and each participant was assessed at multiple ages. Blocks are nested within age, and age and participant are crossed, with each participant being assessed at all ages, and all ages containing data from all participants. Here is a simplified subset of the data to show the general structure. In reality I have more blocks, the actual dataset contains 97 participants, 20 blocks, and 4 ages. Blocks will be modelled as continuous and a linear slope estimated, whereas Age will be treated as categorical, a factor with 4 levels.
   Subject Stimulus Block   Age    RT
     <dbl> <fct>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1   10010 High         1     1 1136
 2   10010 High         2     1 1111 
 3   10010 High         3     1 1220 
 4   10010 Low          1     1 1224
 5   10010 Low          2     1  862 
 6   10010 Low          3     1  893 
 7   10010 High         1     2  849 
 8   10010 High         2     2  904 
 9   10010 High         3     2  878 
10   10010 Low          1     2  893 
11   10010 Low          2     2  863 
12   10010 Low          3     2  851 
13   10010 High         1     3  863 
14   10010 High         2     3  635 
15   10010 High         3     3  603 
16   10010 Low          1     3  928
17   10010 Low          2     3  606 
18   10010 Low          3     3  568 
19   10010 High         1     4  623 
20   10010 High         2     4  538 
21   10010 High         3     4  544 
22   10010 Low          1     4  610 
23   10010 Low          2     4  670
24   10010 Low          3     4  558

Our main question is how age influences the RT differences between stimulus types. However, we would like to control for the large differences in baseline RT and RT improvements with age. With later ages baseline RT becomes smaller, and slopes flatten (less room to improve). See figure below. This makes sense and is exactly what we expected.

So I believe the fixed effects structure is unambiguous, we want Stimulus * Block * Age, however I am not certain what would be the most appropriate random effects structure. This question described a similar situation with different climate models (Age) at different times (Block) and different initial conditions (Subject). Ben Bolker's response to that query makes me think that the appropriate model in our case would be:
RT ~ Stimulus*Block*Age + (Stimulus*Block | Subject:Age)

So we would capture differences in intercepts and slopes for each subject and each age, without having a separate random effects term for Age, as that would be redundant with its fixed effect. Am I correct in this reasoning?

Since each subject was assessed at different ages and age impacts people differently, I don't see a reason why you shouldn't fit RT ~ Stimulus*Block*Age + (Stimulus*Block*Age | Subject). It might be necessary to simplify the random effects if you encounter convergence issues or random effects estimates at the boundary (0 or 1) but you should probably start with the full model.

The name of the "Block" variable seems unfortunate. It basically encodes some kind of training effect. In my research area a "block" is something different (see "randomized (complete) block design") and a block would usually be the grouping variable of random effects and thus a factor variable.
